# How to read nested value using shift operation in JOLT

Tags: jolt

May be this is very basic but I am new to JOLT and I am not getting the expected output after several attempts.
I am trying to read a nested value using shift operation.
Basically the value of person is dynamic and based on this value, I need to read the value from profession object.
The input I am working on is huge and everything is working as expected, so I am just putting the part where I am stuck.

**Input**:

```json
{
  "person": "Tom Hanks",
  "profession": {
    "Tom Hanks": "actor",
    "Christopher Nolan": "director"
  }
}
```

**Expected output**:

```json
{
  "output" : "actor"
}
```

I am trying to achieve this using something like below. I know this is not correct format but just putting it to know if there is something like this which can be used to get the expected output.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@(1,profession).@(1,person)": "output"
    }
 }
]
```

Can someone please help.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

I transformed the value as a key to match it with **&** operator. Maybe a more elegant way exists.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "profession": "@(1,person)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "&": "output"
      }
    }
  }
]
```